# Jacobian and Eigenvalues: is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, \ and so cannot be used for replacing

Tags: differential-equations

I have seen many solutions to this error for finding jacobian and eigenvalues and tried but they are not working for me.

Here is the code:

```
A0 = -12.95;
B0 = 0.045;
A1 = 17.92;
B1 = -0.057;
C1 = 0.01;
de1 = -C1*x'[t] == 
   0.01 (x[t]^(-1/3) - x[t]^(-1)) + Log[1 - x[t]^(-1)] + 
    x[t]^(-1) + (A0 + B0*y[t] - A1 - B1*y[t]) x[t]^(-2) + 
   2*(A1 + B1*y[t])*x[t]^(-3);
de2 = y'[t] == 2.24 x[t] - (y[t] - 300);
eq = NSolve[{de1, de2} == {0, 0}, {x[t], y[t]}]
j = D[{de1, de2}, {x[t], y[t]}]
j /. eq[[1]]
j /. eq[[2]]
```

Answer (score 1):

I assumed that you want to determine the jacobian at an equilibrium point. Given an autonomous dynamical system such as

$$
\dot x = f_1(x,y)\\
\dot y = f_2(x,y)
$$

the equilibrium points are the solutions for

$$
0 = f_1(x^*,y^*)\\
0 = f_2(x^*,y^*)
$$

at this points normally we need to find the jacobian to linearize the dynamics around the equilibrium points.

$$
J = \nabla f
$$

Follows the script considering

$$
\cases{f_1(x,y) =\frac{2 (17.92\, -0.057 y(t))}{x(t)^3}+\frac{0.102 y(t)-30.87}{x(t)^2}+0.01
   \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{x(t)}}-\frac{1}{x(t)}\right)+\frac{1}{x(t)}+\log
   \left(1-\frac{1}{x(t)}\right)\\
f_2(x,y) = 2.24 x(t)-y(t)+300
}
$$

```
Clear[x, y, t]
A0 = -12.95;
B0 = 0.045;
A1 = 17.92;
B1 = -0.057;
C1 = 0.01;
f = {0.01 (x[t]^(-1/3) - x[t]^(-1)) + Log[1 - x[t]^(-1)] + x[t]^(-1) + (A0 + B0*y[t] - A1 - B1*y[t]) x[t]^(-2) + 2*(A1 + B1*y[t])*x[t]^(-3), 
2.24 x[t] - (y[t] - 300)};
eq = Quiet@NSolve[f == 0, {x[t], y[t]}, Reals][[1]];
j = Grad[f, {x[t], y[t]}]
j0 = j /. eq

(*{{-0.00858706, 0.0106373}, {2.24, -1}}*)
```